# Is there an equivalent package to "iptables-services" in Debian 9 Stretch?

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall, systemd, startup

I would like to administer my firewall by good, old-fashioned `iptables` commands saved by `iptables-save` instead of `ufw` or `firewalld`. For RHEL, there is a neat little package called `iptables-services` that does just that. (See [here](https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-disable-firewalld-use-iptables/)) For Debian, there doesn't seem to be one.

I just could slap `iptables-restore </etc/default/iptables` into `/etc/rc.local` and leave it at that, but I'd like a cleaner setup. If it can come as a systemctl unit it'd be ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [iptables-persistent](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/iptables-persistent).